# How can I scroll Silverlight pages horizontally with touch gestures (1 finger, up and down)

Tags: silverlight, scroll, touch, scrollviewer

I have a touchable silverlight application where i want to show information. So I use a ScrollViewer to scroll down or up, but the handling is not the best because it is hard to hit the scrollviewer, so i want to scroll down and up also with finger gestures like we now it from the iPhone.

My first idea was to implement a class which is derived from ScrollViewer, but thanks to Microsoft who sealed the ScrollViewer class in Silverlight, so i can't use this method.

I have heard about Touch.FrameReported (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894494(v=vs.95).aspx), but i can't find an example for silverlight pages how to use it. I don't use canvas as in the link.

Has somebody an idea how to use it or another method to scroll with touch gestures? i only need it for 1 finger gesture to scroll pages.

Every suggestion is welcome!

Comment: On your `ScrollViewer` add `Background="White"` to it. Or whatever color you prefer, or even just Transparent to give hittestvisibility to the whole thing and try it again, you'll likely find your ScrollViewer will now work as you'd like.

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't work. I have many buttons on that page, I think if I click on one then it consumes the click event and won't throw an mouseleftbuttondown event.

Question: If i use this method with a touch screen, would the mouseleftbuttondown event will be thrown?